# Why is `colSums(A, ,2)` valid syntax? - looks like an empty argument

Tags: r

I'm reading some code that's highly optimized for speed on arrays, and it's using `colSums` in place of `apply` in several cases.

First: Can someone explain why this syntax is valid, please?  It appears to my eye as if an argument is left empty.  Rstudio also flags these lines as missing arguments.  I even resorted to an AI chatbot, which incorrectly predicted the results and output dimensions when using `colSums` this way.

Second: Does anyone have a mnemonic or thinking device to help translate mentally between these two equivalent calls? `colSums` does not seem an intuitive way to handle arrays higher than two dimensions.  I understand it's an optimized method of summing an array along some dimension, it's just hard to mentally parse.

Reprex:

```r
A <- array(1:(2*3*4), dim=c(2,3,4))
A
colSums(A, ,2) 
# equivalent apply statement 
apply(A, 3, sum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since R functions parameter are evaulated lazily, it's not a problem to have missing arguments unless you try to use them. For example this will run fine

```
foo <- function(a, b, c) {
  a + c
}

foo(1, ,5)
# [1] 6
```

The `na.rm` parameter isn't evaluated in the R environment. If you look at the source of `colSums` you'll see it makes a call to `.Internal` to it has slightly different evaluation rules there but the idea is basically the same. It's using a default so it's not evaluating the parameter.

I guess your second question is about the `dim=` parameter. From the help page, it says

> `dims` integer: Which dimensions are regarded as ‘rows’ or ‘columns’ to sum over. For row*, the sum or mean is over dimensions dims+1, ...; for col* it is over dimensions 1:dims.

So since you are using `colSums` a dim of 2 means to sum over dimensions 1:2 which is like the complement of how you would specify it using `apply`

Comment: First: thank you for the lazy eval reminder - I recall reading this in advanced R, but sometimes it's hard to recognize out in the wild.
Second: The docstring is actually helpful, and for some reason your phrasing made it come into focus.  I'd also goofed by reading the `.colSums` docs instead when I was too tired.
Many thanks!

Comment: You might have `foo <- function(a, b =2, c) a + b + c` and call `foo(1,,5)`. The issue of lazy evaluation is tangential here.

Comment: @moodymudskipper true. In this case the fact it had a default parameter value was more important than the lazy evaluation. Good point.

Comment: Thanks all for helping tease out the nuance.  For posterity, leaving the argument space blank is a  small performance improvement over supplying all arguments, or calling all the applicable arguments by name (~0.015s over 1mil cycles).  `colSums(A, dims=2)` seems to be fastest of all, on average.